# useRef value reinitialising on re render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-ref

```
import AccordionSummary from '@mui/material/AccordionSummary';
import DirectionsBusIcon from '@mui/icons-material/DirectionsBus';
import DirectionsWalkIcon from '@mui/icons-material/DirectionsWalk';
import { Box } from "@mui/material";
import { useRef } from 'react';

const RouteSummary = (props) => {

    const expanded = useRef(0)

    const handleClick = ()=>{
        expanded.current++
        props.onClick()
    }
    console.log("testing",expanded)

    return(
        <AccordionSummary expanded ={expanded} onClick = {handleClick} key={Math.random()}
        aria-controls="panel1a-content"
        sx={{width:"100%",display:"flex",paddingLeft:"2rem"}}
        >{props.routeObj.map((stepObj) =>{
            return <Box key={Math.random()} sx={{display:"flex"}}>
            {stepObj.mode==="WALKING"?<DirectionsWalkIcon/>:<DirectionsBusIcon/>} {stepObj.busNumber?
            <Box sx={{backgroundColor:"#FBCB0A",marginRight:"0.5rem",borderRadius:"5px",padding:"0.2rem"}}>
                {stepObj.busNumber}
                </Box>:null}
            </Box>}).reduce((prev, curr) => [prev, ' > ', curr])}
        </AccordionSummary>
    )
}

export default RouteSummary;
```

The value of expanded changes back to zero after a rerender which I cannot understand.
I know that useRef should persist across renders so I don't understand this behaviour.

Comment: You should almost never need to do this: `key={Math.random()}`, read about keys in react docs. If you have done similar thing to `<RouteSummary/>` too, that could be the issue

Comment: thanks, yes I know this is a cheat method thanks, didn't think it could impact useRef at all

Comment: have you tried  `<AccordionSummary expanded={expanded.current} `

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava thank you very much I fixed key values in parent components and this worked

Comment: Also you can use state variables if you want component to rerender after state change

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava in this case I did not want to initialise a re render

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem was this:

```
key={Math.random()}
```

you likely used this also on parent components. When reacts reconciliation algorithm encounters a different key on next render for the same component on same spot in component hierarchy, it will *unmount the component and mount new one* - that's why the `useRef`s value was being lost too.

That's why using `Math.random()` as a key is usually bad idea.